# How to measure the electrostatic field outside of a battery?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, electric-fields, batteries, experimental-technique

The eletric field of a battery should look roughly like that:

[image]

Assuming $1,5\,\mathrm{V}$ voltage and a distance of $5\cdot 10^{-2}\,\mathrm{m}$, the mean electric field should be in the order of magnitude of $30\,\frac{\mathrm{V}}{\mathrm{m}}$.

How can I experimentally measure this field?

Ideally I want to measure the field strength and direction for a grid of points (say 15 cm x 15 cm and 15x15 points) and draw the vector field from that data.

I considered using an electric [field meter](https://www.leybold-shop.com/catalog/product/view/id/2685/s/electric-field-meter-s-524080/category/3568/) but all devices I found are to large and designed to measure much stronger fields.

Since the field is such small the experiment hast do be shielded carefully from fields from other sources such maybe the electrostatically charged hand of the experimentator.

So I am looking for a suggestion of what measurement device I should use and of how to set up the experiment to make it work.

Maybe there are also some "tricks" to get the result a bit more indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [conductive paper](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FGEI50M) like in the following [experimental setup](http://www.auburn.edu/cosam//departments/physics/intro-courses/ugrad-lab/physics1500/lab-files/Electric%20Fields%20Lab.pdf):
[image]
In short, measure the voltage at points on a grid with a voltmeter, and take the gradient to get the electric field.

Comment: Hm. Thanks. Your setup seems to work well with 10 V, I will try it if it works also with the 1,5 V of my battery.

Comment: With this setup, you are measuring potential distribution (voltage drop) map between two electrodes attached to the conductive paper. It is an interesting experiment, but it does not tell you anything about the electrostatic field around a battery.

Comment: ...unless, of course, the battery is inserted in the middle of the paper (with the paper cut out around it and point contacts made near the battery terminals), in which case the 2D potential distribution map will be similar to the cross-section of the battery's electrostatic field.  Sorry @cms, if I misunderstood your idea.